# .Net Core OData 8.0 endpoint lowercaseand custom name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, odata

is it possible to set any name for an OData endpoint? I can't figure it out, I found some examples of routing to lowercase, but that's not what I need right now. Here is a working example that exposes the /Customers API.

Controller

```
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [ODataRouteComponent("api/v1")] 
    public class CustomersController : ODataController 
    {
        [EnableQuery]
        [HttpGet("Customers")]
        public async IQueryable<Customer>()
        {
            return Ok(....);
        }
    }
```

Startup

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt =>
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    builder.EntitySet<TestModel>("Customers") 
           .EntityType
           .Select()
           .Count()
           .Filter()
           .OrderBy();

    opt.AddRouteComponents("api/v1", builder.GetEdmModel());
});
```

What if I want to change Customers to customer-data, for example? I tried renaming the HttpGet, method, controller or model builder, but nothing helped. Has anyone dealt with this before? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have a controller and receiving an HTTP Get where the body of the request is the Get.  The method is deserializing the body data and putting in to a class object IQueryable<Customer>.  Is you body data a Customer or Customer-Data?  You may need a base class and inherited classes to have more than one type of body data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using OData 8, the attribute routing can be **disabled** during service configuration as follows:

```
services.AddControllers().AddOData(options => options.EnableAttributeRouting = false);
```

Please check your Startup.cs or Program.cs file, make sure you are not disable the Attribute Routing.

Then you can refer to the following code, it works well in Asp.net 6 and Asp.net 7 API application, and I installed the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.12` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 5.0.0`:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ODataRouteComponent("api/v1")]
public class CustomersController : ODataController
{
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private static List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>(
        Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(idx => new Customer
        {
            Id = idx,
            Name = $"Customer {idx}",
            Orders = new List<Order>(
                Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(dx => new Order
                {
                    Id = (idx - 1) * 2 + dx,
                    Amount = random.Next(1, 9) * 10
                }))
        }));

    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet("odata/getallcustomer")]
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        return Ok(customers);
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet("odata/getcustomerbyid/({key})")]
    public ActionResult GetCustomById([FromRoute] int key)
    {
        var item = customers.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id.Equals(key));

        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(item);
    }
}
```

And the Program.cs file as below:

```
using Core6API.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;
using Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container. 
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.EntityType<Order>();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddOData(
    options => options.Select()
    .Filter()
    .OrderBy()
    .Expand()
    .Count()
    .SetMaxTop(null)
    .AddRouteComponents(
        "api/v1",
        modelBuilder.GetEdmModel()));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The models:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

After running the application, the result as below:
[image]

More detail information about using OData, see:

[Getting Started with ASP.NET Core OData 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio)

[Routing in ASP.NET Core OData 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/fundamentals/routing-overview?tabs=net60)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do something like:

```
builder.EntitySet<TestModel>("customer-data") 
       .EntityType
       .Select()
       .Count()
       .Filter()
       .OrderBy();
```

Then, in your controller, you would update the HttpGet attribute to reflect the new endpoint name:

```
[HttpGet("customer-data")]
public async IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomerData()
{
    return Ok(....);
}
```

Don't forget to update the controller:

```
[ODataRouteComponent("api/v1/customer-data")] 
public class CustomersController : ODataController 
{
    // ...
}
```